# "rails g model" with associations on the CLI and other questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm starting out with Ruby and Ruby on Rails (RoR). It's my first day, reading the guides.

I'm trying to generate a scaffold with various models, for instance `Game` and `Platform`. I'm trying to replace an existing, way outdated [Symfony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony) PHP project and picked Ruby/RoR for learning purposes, also because I was impressed with hotwire from the blog demo video.

A `Game` `has_one` `Platform`, a `Platform` `has_many` `Games`.

Or

```
type Game {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  slug: String
  platform: Platform!
}

type Platform {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  slug: String
  games: [Game]
}
```

For now I'd like to generate those two models with "rails g scaffold". I read on other questions that one has to use ":references", but I can't find that keyword anywhere in any guide of activerecord.

`rails g scaffold Game name:string slug:string platform:references`

is what I have so far. Is it even possible to define associations with foreign keys via the cli?

What is the typical workflow when generating models/scaffolds? Do you just start with the bare minimum of the model and manually edit the migration, add the foreign key and associations?

I guess I'm more looking for a Discord server for Ruby, Ruby on Rails, or other. I have so many questions, but don't feel like this belongs here, because I would create question after question. But for now let's stick to this. (Side question, what is the de-facto standard when it comes to authentication and authorization in Ruby on Rails? And another question, is there somelike that auto-slugifies, see the name and slug connection?)

How can I express model associations on the command line?

Comment: You should generate `Platform` first and then yes that scaffold is correct. You can find basic details on `references` [Here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) and [Here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) and more technical details [Here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference)

Comment: > What is the typical workflow when generating models/scaffolds?
Personally I don't generate scaffolds, as they create to many files at once. I only generate migrations, and write other files by hand

Comment: Beware that a standard reason for questions to be closed is **Needs more focus** *This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.*

Answer (score 0):

> Is it even possible to define associations with foreign keys via the CLI?

Yes.

You can define `belongs_to` associations via the generators - as it's the only association that’s actually backed by a database column on *this* models table. You cannot define `has_one`, `has_many` or `has_and_belongs_belongs_to_many` via the generators—they must be added to the model later.

> For now I'd like to generate those 2 models with "rails g scaffold". I read on other questions that one has to use ":references" but I can't find that keyword anywhere in any guide of activerecord.

It is not really a keyword. Rather `references/belongs_to` (the later is an alias) are column types (well kind of) when generating models or migrations.

If you run `rails g model -h` it details the options:

> You can also consider `references` as a kind of type. For instance, if
> you run:
>
> `bin/rails generate model photo title:string album:references`
>
> It will generate an `album_id` column. You should generate these kinds
> of fields when you will use a `belongs_to` association, for instance.

It also adds `belongs_to :album` in the model when you use it with the model generator.

> What is the typical workflow when generating models/scaffolds? Do you just start with the bare minimum of the model and manually edit the migration, add fk and associations?

Scaffolds are mainly useful for rapid prototyping or when you're learning as way to see the "Ruby on Rails Way" of defining resources. They tend to generate way more code then you actually need and will outrun your tests.

Generators in general are just a tool and it’s often easier and faster to just edit the resulting files than to get the exact invocation of the generator right.

Comment: So I can just write `rails g model Blog posts:has_many` ?

Comment: Dude, I literally wrote: "You cannot define has_one, has_many or has_and_belongs_belongs_to_many via the generators".